# How to run StarCluster with AWS IAM Role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, cluster-computing, starcluster

How can I modify [StarCluster](http://star.mit.edu/cluster/docs/latest/index.html) config or code to include [IAM Role](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html)?

So that when I do this:

```
starcluster start mycluster
```

The IAM Role can be automatically activated in EC2 instances (master and nodes).
I did try to [look around](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=starcluster%20iam%20role&oq=starcluster%20iam%20role&aqs=chrome..69i57.10123j0j7) but of no avail info.

Comment: The StarCluster documentation makes no reference to IAM Roles. [This person](http://star.mit.edu/cluster/mlarchives/2314.html) has made a modification that can do it, and there's [a discussion](https://github.com/jtriley/StarCluster/issues/508) about it.

Comment: @neversaint I think Starcluster does not support IAM role. Use scripting code for such an implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Starcluster does not support this out the box. The automated solution would be to write a plugin (I couldn't find any) in python that uses the boto AWS library to add IAM roles to instances.

If automation isn't required, then the good news is that AWS [announced this week](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/new-attach-an-aws-iam-role-to-an-existing-amazon-ec2-instance-by-using-the-aws-cli/?sc_channel=sm&sc_campaign=rolesforrunninginstances&sc_publisher=tw&sc_medium=social&sc_content=read-post&sc_country=global&sc_geo=global&sc_category=ec2&sc_outcome=launch) the ability to change IAM roles of existing instances. You would have to use a similar workflow to automate the process.